# How to customize the output of node content in Drupal 6?

Tags: 6, theming, nodes, paging

I am looking to customise the templated output of the `$content` variable in `node.tpl.php` Can you tell me how I could achieve this? Is is possible with another template file?

The reason for this is to achieve AJAX pagination thus I need an ID on node_body and also to pull out the paging nav from this same DIV.

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the available them files where you can get `$content`

> node--[type|nodeid].tpl.php
>
> base template: node.tpl.php

Theme hook suggestions are made based on these factors, listed from the most specific template to the least. Drupal will use the most specific template it finds:

> node--nodeid.tpl.php
>
> node--type.tpl.php

node.tpl.php

See [`node.tpl.php`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7) in the Drupal API documentation for more information.

[Drupal 7 Template (Theme Hook) Suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089656)